# iPhone build failed on using Aviary SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, aviary

I am creating an Iphone application wherein I need to process image and display it on application. I went through **Aviary SDK** which indeed really appeals to me as a developer. I went through its [**documentation**](http://www.aviary.com/ios-documentation) which I understood very clearly.

The problem I am facing is in building the application. I receive a build failed when I try building application. I also went through GitHub repository [**CSPicker**](https://github.com/cspicker/AviarySDKSample). Build also fails for that. I did every specific change mentioned in Prerequisites in the documentation. Still no success.

Following is the error I am getting:

> Command /Xcode4.2/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

I am using XCode 4.2 and iOS 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what is the problem. Likely you did not add necessary libraries to build with. Or used old compiler in settings (not LLVM)
As of right now Aviary has new version of SDK with decent description what needs to be done at http://www.aviary.com/ios-documentation